# Python: How to find all ways to decode a string?

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve this problem but it fails with input "226".

**Problem**:
A message containing letters from A-Z is being encoded to numbers using the following mapping:

```
'A' -> 1
'B' -> 2
...
'Z' -> 26
```

Given a non-empty string containing only digits, determine the total number of ways to decode it.

**My Code:**

```
class Solution:
    def numDecodings(self, s: str) -> int:
        decode =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]
        ways = []
        for d in decode:
            for i in s:
                if str(d) == s or str(d) in s:
                    ways.append(d)
                if int(i) in decode:
                    ways.append(str(i))
        return len(ways)
```

My code returns 2. It only takes care of combinations (22,6) and (2,26).

It should be returning 3, so I'm not sure how to take care of the (2,2,6) combination.

Comment: why dont you use a dictionary `{'A':1,'B':2,.....'Z':26}`. Then you search for the key in the dict, and based on that pick the value. Isn't that simpler? Or if you are giving numbers and want alphabets, then switch the dictionary to `{1:'A',2:'B'....,26:'Z'}`

Comment: I wanted to try to solve it with an iterative approach first. I'll try that next, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this problem can be broken down into many subproblems thus can be solved recursively

1. Subproblem 1 = when the last digit of the string is valid ( i.e. non zero number ) for that you can just recur for (n-1) digits left

```py
if s[n-1] > "0":  
        count = number_of_decodings(s,n-1)
```

2. Subproblem 2 = when last 2 digits form a valid number ( less then 27 ) for that you can just recur for remaining (n-2) digits

```py
if (s[n - 2] == '1' or (s[n - 2] == '2' and s[n - 1] < '7') ) :  
        count += number_of_decodings(s, n - 2)
```

3. Base Case = length of the string is 0 or 1

```py
if n == 0 or n == 1 :  
        return 1
```

EDIT: A quick searching on internet , I found another ( more interesting ) method to solve this particular problem which uses dynamic programming to solve this problem

```py
# A Dynamic Programming based function 
# to count decodings  
def countDecodingDP(digits, n):  
  
    count = [0] * (n + 1); # A table to store  
                           # results of subproblems  
    count[0] = 1;  
    count[1] = 1;  
  
    for i in range(2, n + 1):  
  
        count[i] = 0;  
  
        # If the last digit is not 0, then last 
        # digit must add to the number of words  
        if (digits[i - 1] > '0'):  
            count[i] = count[i - 1];  
  
        # If second last digit is smaller than 2 
        # and last digit is smaller than 7, then 
        # last two digits form a valid character  
        if (digits[i - 2] == '1' or 
           (digits[i - 2] == '2' and 
            digits[i - 1] < '7') ):  
            count[i] += count[i - 2];  
  
    return count[n];
```

the above solution solves the problem in complexity of O(n) and uses the similar method as that of fibonacci number problem

source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-possible-decodings-given-digit-sequence/

Answer (score 2):

This seemed like a natural for recursion.  Since I was bored, and the first answer didn't use recursion and didn't return the actual decodings, I thought there was room for improvement.  For what it's worth...

```
def encodings(str, prefix = ''):
    encs = []
    if len(str) > 0:
        es = encodings(str[1:], (prefix + ',' if prefix else '') + str[0])
        encs.extend(es)
        if len(str) > 1 and int(str[0:2]) <= 26:
            es = encodings(str[2:], (prefix + ',' if prefix else '') + str[0:2])
            encs.extend(es)
    return encs if len(str) else [prefix]
```

This returns a list of the possible decodings.  To get the count, you just take the length of the list.  Here a sample run:

```
encs = encodings("123")
print("{} {}".format(len(encs), encs))
```

with result:

```
3 ['1,2,3', '1,23', '12,3']
```

Another sample run:

```
encs = encodings("123123")
print("{} {}".format(len(encs), encs))
```

with result:

```
9 ['1,2,3,1,2,3', '1,2,3,1,23', '1,2,3,12,3', '1,23,1,2,3', '1,23,1,23', '1,23,12,3', '12,3,1,2,3', '12,3,1,23', '12,3,12,3']
```

Comment: genius, how did you come up with recursion? Please show me how.